# script not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm very new to linux, I'm trying to get names of .ogg files from a text file and take mp3 files of directory music and rename and move them to a different directory with the name of that file line by line but not working. [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) shows this output:

> f referrenced but not assigned

I can't figure it out.

```
#!/bin/bash
while -r read f;
do
for mp3 in ./music/*; 
   do
     "mv $mp3 /home/shady/Music/$f"
                  ^––SC2154 f is referenced but not assigned.
   break
   done
done < /home/shady/piku.txt
```

**Update**:

```
*

motegi_2004.ogg
assen_2004.ogg
phakisa_2004.ogg
donington_2004.ogg
catalunya_2004.ogg
strange_symbol.ogg
credits.ogg
philip_2004.ogg
jerez_2004.ogg
brno_2004.ogg
sepang_2004.ogg
estoril_2004.ogg
motogp.ogg
frontend.ogg
valencia_2004.ogg
lemans_2004.ogg
rio_2004.ogg
mugello_2004.ogg
sachsenring_2004.ogg
thqintro.ogg
qatar_2004.ogg
training_2004.ogg
climax.ogg
```

*

piku.txt contains these names and the for loop breaks after moving the first file as ogg in a different  directory so when the wile loop takes the next name from line 2 from piku.txt the for loop takes the first file it finds in the directory in our case thats the file 2 cause we already moved previous one to a different directory .And dont worry about mp3s bening renamed as oggs ,this is just a test.I just wanna know if this works

edit:2

```
 1  #!/bin/bash
   2  while read -r f
   3  do
   4    for mp3 in /home/shady/Desktop/music/* 
   5    do
   6                mv -i "$mp3" "/home/shady/Music/$f"
   7                break
   8    done
   9    done < /home/shady/piku.txt
  10
```

i assigned full path now for the for loop but it gives me

> mv: cannot stat ‘/home/shady/Desktop/music/*’: No such file or
>   directory

---

```
*

motegi_2004.ogg
assen_2004.ogg
phakisa_2004.ogg
donington_2004.ogg
catalunya_2004.ogg
strange_symbol.ogg
credits.ogg
philip_2004.ogg
jerez_2004.ogg
brno_2004.ogg
sepang_2004.ogg
estoril_2004.ogg
motogp.ogg
frontend.ogg
valencia_2004.ogg
lemans_2004.ogg
rio_2004.ogg
mugello_2004.ogg
sachsenring_2004.ogg
thqintro.ogg
qatar_2004.ogg
training_2004.ogg
climax.ogg
```

*

piku.txt contains these names and the for loop breaks after moving the first file as ogg in a different  directory so when the wile loop takes the next name from line 2 from piku.txt the for loop takes the first file it finds in the directory in our case thats the file 2 cause we already moved previous one to a different directory .And dont worry about mp3s bening renamed as oggs ,this is just a test.I just wanna know if this works

edit:2

```
 1  #!/bin/bash
   2  while read -r f
   3  do
   4    for mp3 in /home/shady/Desktop/music/* 
   5    do
   6                mv -i "$mp3" "/home/shady/Music/$f"
   7                break
   8    done
   9    done < /home/shady/piku.txt
  10
```

i assigned full path now for the for loop but it gives me

> mv: cannot stat ‘/home/shady/Desktop/music/*’: No such file or
>   directory

Comment: What is the purpose of  `-r` option to the while loop? `while` is a shell keyword not a program that accepts parameters as far as I know

Comment: can you update your question to include the contents of the text file you are trying to read and what output you are hoping your program will produce

Answer (score 4):

The `-r` isn't helping here, try placing it **after** the `read`.

Optional: After `while` and `for` you either need `;` or a newline, but you don't need both!  Since you have newlines before the `do` keywords, you can remove those two `;`s.

Quotes should go around arguments, not the whole command:

```
    mv -i "$mp3" "/home/shady/Music/$f"
```

I added `-i` so that `mv` will not try to overwrite any existing files.

Crucially, you have a loop inside a loop.  You can't move one mp3 file multiple times!  If you want to mix two sets of filenames together, you could try using `paste` to pull lines from each file and combine them:

```
paste <(find ./music/* -maxdepth 1 -printf '"%p"\n') /home/shady/piku.txt | sed 's+^+mv -i +' > /tmp/move_my_files.sh
```

Then you can look at the file you generated and see if it does what you want.

(You may need to put quotes around all the filenames in piku.txt, if they contain spaces.)

If you are happy with how the `move_my_files.sh` script looks, you can run it:

```
bash -e -x /tmp/move_my_files.sh
```

If I have misunderstood your intention, you may need to explain better, including the content of piku.txt and the expected result, and how `mp3` files become `ogg` files!

Comment: I agree with all of this

Comment: actually - I dont think they have a loop inside a loop. the inner loop breaks, so only one iteration runs

Comment: You are correct. So only one mp3 will be moved (the first one selected by `*`), and then the next line will be read from `piku.txt`.  You can put `echo` before `mv` while you are working on your script, so you can see what the script is trying to do.